# Как отобразить с помощью stream строку: aaabccccCCaB в следующем виде: 3ab4c2CaB?

Tags: java, java-stream

P.S. У меня не получается отсортировать по нормальному, чтобы сохранить порядок как при вводе (aaabccccCCaB), и мой стрим считает все одинаковые эл-ты, т.е. выдает след результат: 4aBb2C4c вместо 3ab4c2CaB.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream((new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine().split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .forEach((el, count) -> {
                if (count>1)
                    System.out.print(count + el);
                if (count<=1)
                    System.out.print(el);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам это делать с помощью Stream-ов? Обычным циклом с использованием индексов это делается просто и понятно.

Comment: У меня такая задача - решить с помощью stream, с помощью циклов я думаю справлюсь..

Comment: Это называется [RLE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
String text = "aaabccccCCaB";

Arrays.stream(text.split(""))
    .collect(Collector.of(ArrayList<StringBuilder>::new, (o, s) -> {
      if (o.size() != 0 && o.get(o.size()-1).charAt(0) == s.charAt(0)) {
        StringBuilder sb = o.get(o.size() - 1);
          sb.append(s);
      } else {
        o.add(new StringBuilder(s));
      }
    }, (o, o2) -> null))
    .forEach(sb -> System.out.print((sb.length()>1 ? sb.length() : "") + sb.substring(0,1)));
```

PS Не сработает на паралельных стримах из-за:

```
(o, o2) -> null)
```

Тоже с вынесением BiConsumer:

```
BiConsumer<List<StringBuilder>, String> biConsumer = (list, s) -> {
  if (list.size() != 0 && (list.get(list.size() - 1)).charAt(0) == s.charAt(0)) {
    StringBuilder sb = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    sb.append(s);
  } else {
    list.add(new StringBuilder(s));
  }
};

System.out.println(Arrays.stream(text.split(""))
    .collect(Collector.of(ArrayList::new, biConsumer, (o, o2) -> null))
    .stream().map(sb -> (sb.length()>1 ? sb.length() : "") + sb.substring(0,1))
    .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Еще один вариант:

```
String text = "aaabccccCCaB";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
IntStream.range(0, text.length()+1)
    .filter(value -> value==0 || value == text.length() || text.charAt(value) != text.charAt(value-1))
    //или так
    .reduce((l, r) -> {
      result.append(r-l > 1 ? r-l : "")
      .append(text.substring(l, l+1));
      return r;})
    //или сразу выводить на консоль без StringBuilder
    //.reduce((l, r) -> {
    //  System.out.print(r-l > 1 ? r-l : "");
    //  System.out.print(text.substring(l, l+1));
    //  return r;})
    .isPresent();

System.out.println(result.toString());.
```

Comment: Наверно, это один из наименее костыльных вариантов реализации на stream-ах, но, согласитесь, бОльшую часть кода здесь занимает "не-stream-овый".

Comment: Согласен, тут бОльшая часть кода - реализация функциональных интерфейсов. Вынес самый большой в отдельную переменную

Comment: Спасибо, из всех вариантов самый толковый и простой имхо через .filter и .reduce и сразу на консоль :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "aaabccccCCaB";
//разбиваем на группы
String groups = Arrays.stream(text.split(""))
        .reduce("",
                (l, r) -> {
                    int length = l.length();
                    if (length > 0 && l.toCharArray()[length - 1] == r.toCharArray()[0]) {
                        return l + r;
                    } else {
                        return l + "@" + r;
                    }
                });
//"схлапываем" группы
String result = Arrays.stream(groups.split("@"))//.parallel()
        .filter(group -> !group.isEmpty())
        .map(group -> (group.length() > 1 ? group.length(): "") + group.substring(0, 1))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result); //3ab4c2CaB
```

Более короткий вариант той же логики:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(text.split(""))//.parallel()
        .reduce((l, r) -> l + (l.charAt(l.length() - 1) == r.charAt(0) ? "" : "@") + r)
        .map(groups -> groups.split("@"))
        .map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)//.parallel()
        .map(group -> (group.length() > 1 ? group.length() : "") + group.substring(0, 1))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result); //3ab4c2CaB
```

Второй вариант хорошо параллелится (указал `//.parallel()`) там, где это можно сделать. Первый вариант можно распараллелить только после разбиения на группы - во 2м стриме.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать как-то так, но учитывая, что символы должны обрабатываться друг за другом - это дело не параллелится:

```java
String str = "aaabccccCCaB";

List<Tuple2<Character, Long>> results = str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
    .collect(
        // create collection to store elements
        LinkedList::new,

        // process each element
        (list, c) -> {
            Tuple2<Character, Long> lastCharacter = list.peekLast();
            if (lastCharacter == null || lastCharacter.f0 != c) {
                list.add(new Tuple2<>(c, 1L));
            } else {
                lastCharacter.f1 += 1;
            }
        },

        // merge lists
        LinkedList::addAll
    );

String result = results.stream()
    .map(tuple -> (tuple.f1 > 1 ? "" + tuple.f1 : "") + tuple.f0)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(result);   // 3ab4c2CaB
```